# Variable names and character encodings

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, sublimetext2

I have [checked](http://mothereff.in/js-variables) that `π` is valid for a JavaScript variable name. Also, when I try writing `var π = Math.PI` in the Chrome console, all is fine.

However, when I include the line `var π = Math.PI` inside a `.js` file written with Sublime Text 2 on a Mac, Chrome complains:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I have tried the encodings UTF-8, UTF-16 LE and UTF-16 BE, but none work. When I execute the line `console.log('π')`, written inside Sublime Text 2 with UTF-8, Chrome prints:

```
Ï€
```

How can I use the JavaScript variable name `π` in Sublime Text 2, so that Chrome understands it?

Comment: Why the heck do you want to use non-ascii characters for variable names?!?!

Comment: Because I love the shortcut `π` for `math.PI`.

Comment: Anybody working with your code will **HATE** you for that. Nobody can type `π` easily.

Comment: var pleaße_dont_do_this;

Comment: Maybe it's only typo, but it should be `Math`, not `math`. Did you try `var π = Math.PI; console.log(π);` in Chrome console? It returns 3.141592653589793 in my browser (but it's on Win7). I also think that using non-ascii characters for scripting is weird, but I like your response about shortcut ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: What? On a mac it's as simple as `Alt + p`.

Comment: @Randomblue: ...and if you're using a Greek keyboard that would be even easier. He's probably never heard about non-latin languages.

Comment: `var ø = sum(frob) / frob.size();`. now can your mac do THAT? `AltGR + o` on a Linux. Far easier to type than `average`.

Comment: @phresnel: You must be kidding right? It's as simple as `Alt + o`.

Comment: @Randomblue: Actually I thought you were kidding about seriously using those international characters just because you can. Now I wonder: Are you or are you not?

Comment: @phresnel: No, Mac handles greek letters like ∑, ø, ß, ∂ etc. very well with the `Alt` + some letter combination. It's also very good with accentuated letters such as é, å, á, ì, etc.

Comment: @Randomblue: Okay, because Linux can handle fractions very well, do you think it is a good idea to go like this: `var ½y = ¼x³ + ¼x²;`.

Comment: @phresnel: Hehe, nice. It's definitely entertaining and an interesting thought experiment. Unfortunately, [this is not legal in JavaScript](http://mothereff.in/js-variables#%C2%BDy).

Comment: a team should agree on using a certain language, be it english (always preferred), or greek, or even german, and use the letters available on any standard keyboard layout for that language. Mixing greek, german, english and maths raises the learning barrier and puts more effort on every programmer. Using one language consistently is burn proof practice. (I'd like to say more, but this is the comment section). Btw, [**APL might be for you**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to make sure you are setting a `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the head of your html or if the charset is different you can set the charset attribute on your script tag:

```
<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! What is the default encoding?

Comment: I believe that the default encoding is entirely dependent upon your web server settings.

Comment: Servers typically send no character encoding information for .js files. This implies that browsers will use the encoding specified in the `charset` parameter of the `script` tag or, if it does not have that parameter, the character encoding of the HTML document, which in turn is determined by its HTTP headers, applicable `meta` tag, or browser guesswork, in that order.